# Change Style of Points

Tags: plotting

I was wondering if it's possible to change the style of a`Point` with another symbol e.g.: cross, x etc...

It may sound weird-it is a Point after all, but I would like to have crosses instead of points in the following code

```
  Manipulate[Module[{data, inside, insidepts}, SeedRandom[n];
  data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 2}];
  insidepts = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x^2 + y^2 < 1];
  inside = Length[insidepts];
  Text@
   Style[
    Column[
     {Graphics[{PointSize[0.0001], Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Blue,
        Point[data]}, ImageSize -> If[format, 500, 350]],
      Row[{"inside: ", inside, "\toutside: ", m - inside, "\ttotal: ",
         m}],
      Row[{"π=4 x ", inside, "/", m, " = ", 4. inside/m}]}], "Label"]],
 {{n, 1, "random seed"}, 1, 1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 1, "sample size"}, 1, 100000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{format, False, "large format"}, {True, False}},
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit faster to create one marker, and use `GeometricTransform` to position it where needed than to use individual placements with `Text` or `Inset`:

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[n];
 data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 2}];
 insidepts = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x^2 + y^2 < 1];
 inside = Length[insidepts];
 Text@Style[
   Column[{Graphics[{PointSize[0.0001], Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Blue, 
       GeometricTransformation[
        Line[{{Offset[{-2, 2}, {0, 0}], 
           Offset[{2, -2}, {0, 0}]}, {Offset[{-2, -2}, {0, 0}], 
           Offset[{2, 2}, {0, 0}]}}], Dynamic[data]]}, 
      ImageSize -> If[format, 500, 350]], 
     Row[{"inside: ", inside, "\toutside: ", m - inside, "\ttotal: ", 
       m}], Row[{"\[Pi]=4 x ", inside, "/", m, " = ", 4. inside/m}]}],
    "Label"], {{n, 1, "random seed"}, 1, 1000, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m, 1, "sample size"}, 1, 100000, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{format, False, "large format"}, {True, 
   False}}, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]
```

I used `Line` with `Offset` coordinates to construct a cross, but you could use `Inset["\[Cross]", {0,0}]` instead.

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi You can make the lines thinner to keep the disk visible, but then it tends to get blurry because of antialiasing (and turning off antialiasing will fill up the region again.)  At the heart of it is that you're necessarily drawing more blue ink with a cross (or any other shape.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really a nice solution! It's not that slow;I think I can hardly tell the difference between that and `Point`.Thank's!

Answer (score 4):

Given your example "point" symbols (cross, plus) and the need for speed if you want live updating in Manipulate, I recommend that you format your symbols as a series of lines, and display *all* of these lines in a single `Line` expression.

The size of the X's is controlled by the parameter of `makeXfun`.

You can use `Opacity` to reduce the inevitable visual density of the "points" in your graphic.

```
makeXfun[r_] := 
 Compile[{{xy, _Real, 1}},
   {{xy + {-r, -r}, xy + {r, r}}, {xy + {-r, r}, xy + {r, -r}}}]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   {Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]},
   {Blue, Opacity[0.5],
     Line[Join @@ makeXfun[0.015] /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {Round[samp^2], 2}]]},
   {Black, Text["Sample size: " <> ToString@Round[samp^2], {0, -1.2}]}
   }, ImageSize -> 400],
 {samp, 1, 300, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For plus symbols instead of X's you would use something like:

```
makePlusfun[r_] := 
  Compile[{{xy, _Real, 1}},
    {{xy + {-r, 0}, xy + {r, 0}}, {xy + {0, r}, xy + {0, -r}}}]
```

Comment: Oh my God! This a very sophisticated solution, I could have never thought of!!!Thank's!

Comment: @Thanos I'm curious, how does the performance of this method compare to that of Brett's solution?  I can't run his on version 7 to compare.

Comment: Brett's solution is a bit faster/lighter. Yours start to become slow from ~7000 while his the critical point is ~10000.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Text`, but it gets much slower than using `Point`.

```
Manipulate[Module[{data, inside, insidepts}, SeedRandom[n];
  data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 2}];
  insidepts = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x^2 + y^2 < 1];
  inside = Length[insidepts];
  Text@Style[
    Column[{Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Blue, 
        Text[Style["\[Cross]", 12], #] & /@ data}, 
       ImageSize -> If[format, 500, 350]], 
      Row[{"inside: ", inside, "\toutside: ", m - inside, "\ttotal: ", m}],
      Row[{"\[Pi]=4 x ", inside, "/", m, " = ", 4. inside/m}]}], "Label"]],
  {{n, 1, "random seed"}, 1, 1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{m, 1, "sample size"}, 1, 100000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{format, False, "large format"}, {True, False}},
  AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are right that it's much slower than `Point`... But it is a decent solution! Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

There is no styling for Point as for plot markers. Hence you can use `Show` with `ListPlot` added to your Graphics.  I use the standard "x" for the `x`. I think from Paletts there might be a better looking cross symbol to use if you search there.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{data, inside, insidepts},
  SeedRandom[n];
  data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 2}];     
  insidepts = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x^2 + y^2 < 1];
  inside = Length[insidepts];

  Text@Style[Column[{
      Show[
       Graphics[
        {
         PointSize[0.0001],
         Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]
         },
        ImageSize -> If[format, 500, 350]
        ], 

        ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Style["x", 9]]
       ],

      Row[{"inside: ", inside, "\toutside: ", m - inside, "\ttotal: ",m}], 
      Row[{"\[Pi]=4 x ", inside, "/", m, " = ", 4. inside/m}]}], "Label"]
  ],

 {{n, 1, "random seed"}, 1, 1000, 1,Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{m, 1, "sample size"}, 1, 100000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{format, False, "large format"}, {True,False}},

 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 ContinuousAction -> False,

 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}
 ]
```

But with so many points you have, I do not see what is the point of this really, as it will not make any difference after few points, it is hard to see what is there any way.  (I also noticed it is a little slower that `Point`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I would like to use crosses in order to compare it with a similar output from matlab-class rules! You are right that it's slower than `Point`... Perhaps I should change it in Matlab where it's easier. No matter what, thank you very much for your answer!